# Having trouble adjusting height of the div items when overlaying a grid on an image

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm using `Vue.js` & `vuetify` to make a **SPA**.

I have a component that has a background image onto which I'm overlaying a grid. The image adjusts its aspect ratio when I change the width of the page.  I want the same behavior on the grid.

I generated the grid using divtable.com/generate.  It just gave me a 12x12  table of divs and some css selectors for them.  I wanted to have precise control of how I overlay the forms on top of this so decided to go this route.

I'm having trouble adjusting height of the div table cells.  The width adjusts just fine and stays aligned, but the height of the cells is constant no matter what.  I'm also bit of a css noob. I don't know if vuetify or vue is doing some overriding of the css in the background.

I tried a lot of things.  Just setting the height property doesn't work for some reason.  I tried to use "scoped" on the style in case something is being overridden.  For some reason the height of the cell won't change no matter what.  Any help is appreciated.  j

A verbatim example of the code can be found here: http://divtable.com/generator/

The only difference is I have the following selectors before the table of divs:

```
img {
    width: 100%;
}
.image-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.image-container .after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Thank you.  Wouldn't ask if I wasn't in a bit of a rush to figure this out by tomorrow.  Any help is appreciated.

Note: I tried setting a min height.  Making it scoped and all sorts of other stuff I found.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle of it?

Comment: I think I may have found the problem.  Still don't know how to solve it.  I'm using vuetify framework and I put my image in a collapsable component.. I think this is overriding the height.

Comment: I put here: http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/#&togetherjs=AJ3JUdpObi  its not very helpful though.  may be difficult to tell whats going on :\

Comment: can you open the chrome inspector and post a screenshot of the elements interested? (table, tr, td etc)

Comment: if you have found your problem and you solved it, answer your own question to keep it as reference for othe rpeople

Answer (score 0):

I decided for the sake of time just to not use an grid overlay at all and just adjust the components over the image using relative positions.  There was no real advantage to using a grid overlay in this case.

From a technical standpoint, I wasn't able to find the exact problem, but it likely wasn't any framework magic, just lack of time in finding the correct CSS selector to adjust.

Thanks for any help.  Much appreciated.

```css
img {
    width: 100%;
}
.image-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 95%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
.image-container .after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
}
#loadControlDevices {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 10.5%;
  margin-left: 1.15%;
}
```

```html
  <div class="image-container" >
      <div style="height: 100%;">
        <img src="scope.ami.png" />
      </div>
      <div class="after">
        <div id="loadControlDevices">
          <v-checkbox id="loadControlCB" name="loadControlCB" label="" filled></v-checkbox>
        </div>
        ... other divs following this ...
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Also, recently found this plugin which may be helpful for grid layout stuff: https://github.com/jbaysolutions/vue-grid-layout